# How jQuery to change a second select list based on the Third select list option and second select based upon first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Why third select option is changing based upon second one. But when first select is selected second one is changing. while go to second third one is not changing
    This is my view.

```
<select name="select1" select="select1">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="america">America</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option data-value="orissa" value="india">Orissa</option>
  <option data-value="telangan" value="india">Telangan</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="america">USA</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>
<select name="select3" id="select3">
  <option value="">Select city</option>
  <option value="orissa">Nal</option>
  <option value="orissa">Mir</option>
  <option value="Telangan">Hyd</option>
  <option value="Telangan">Vija</option>
  <option value="america">KRK</option>
  <option value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
This is my script
<script>
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
    });
  $("#select2").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select3').html(options);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select1 is not working since there is no id attribute for select1 in HTML.

```
<!-- change -->
<select name="select1" select="select1">
<!-- to -->
<select name="select1" id="select1">
```

Also, there seems to be some mismatch between data-values and values of options.

1. try to keep `val` for actual value of the option and `data-value` for its predecessor.
2. Both these value are case sensitive so `'telangan' !== 'Telangan'`

Here's a updated version of your code:

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options).show();
});


$("#select2").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select3').html(options).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="america">America</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option data-value="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
    <option data-value="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
    <option data-value="america" value="america">USA</option>
    <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option data-value="orissa">Nal</option>
    <option data-value="orissa">Mir</option>
    <option data-value="telangan">Hyd</option>
    <option data-value="telangan">Vija</option>
    <option data-value="america">KRK</option>
    <option data-value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks it working fine. But small i want to made. The third select option should not be shown untill first, second is selected.

Comment: You can hide/show the respective select via CSS or JS as per your need. I have modified the code for doing it by JS. Have a look.